# It's not following iteration while I am increasing the counter

Tags: python, algorithm

I am writing the program for prime numbers which are expressed as sum of other consecutive prime numbers and should always start with number 2.

```
    5=2+3
    17=2+3+5+7
    41 =2+3+5+7+11+13
```

My code for finding the prime:

```
def prime():
    num=int(input("enter the number"))
    counter=0
    for num in range(2,num+1):
        if(num%2+num%3)!=0:
            counter+1
        else:
            print(prime())
        print(counter)
print(prime())
```

but I am getting the following output while running the above sample:

```
enter the number5
0
0
0
0
None
```

Whenever it iterates over the loop it prints nothing but only `0`.

Comment: What is your solution?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please read stack overflows [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking a question, which includes concisely describing the question, showing what you have attempted so far in code so that we may reproduce your issue, and what problem you are facing that you need help with.

Comment: Also suggest you read (and follow advice in answers) to [**_Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?_**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The `print(prime()` statement _in the function_ causes it to call itself recursively, which makes it (and the `for` loop inside it) start over from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is most probably based on

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623872/what-is-the-sum-of-the-prime-numbers-up-to-a-prime-number-n

This can be implemented by using storing the primes to list

```
import numpy as np    
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))    
primes = []    
for a in range(2,num):    
  maxInt= int(np.sqrt(a)) + 1    
  for i in range(2,maxInt):   
    if (a%i==0):
      break    
  else:
    primes.append(a)
    if sum(primes) >= num:
        break

print(sum(primes))
print(primes)
```

```
Enter a number: 41

41

[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
```